# How to properly pass a pointer of a struct to epoll_event?

Tags: c, pointers, epoll

Here is my snipped code its just a simple server listening for tcp connections. It was already working if I just pass the fd to the epoll_event data but I need now to pass a pointer to a struct array and I can't make it work. My complete code currently compiles but give me a `general protection ip:406de3 sp:7fffbc86a070 error:` when executed. Can you please check my codes and see if theres a problem specially with the pointers.

```
#define MAX_EVENTS 16  
struct client_data{
    char id;
    char active;
    char disabled;
    int  fd;
};

struct epoll_event  ev;
struct epoll_event  events[MAX_EVENTS];
struct client_data client[16];

int listener_fd = open_socket_function_here();
int running = 1;

ev.events = EPOLLIN;
ev.data.ptr = &listener_fd;    
if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listener_fd, &ev) < 0) {                               
        /* error handling here */
        return -1;
}    

while ( running ) {
    int num_events = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, MAX_EVENTS, 5000);

    /* Check if epoll actually succeed  */
    if ( num_events == -1 ){
        fprintf (stderr,"Error epoll_wait : %s\n", strerror(errno));     
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( num_events == 0 ){
        /* timeout; no event detected  */   
    }
    else{
        for ( i = 0; i < num_events; i++ ){

            if ( ( events[i].data.ptr ==  &listener_fd ) && events[i].events & EPOLLIN ){
                  int new_client_id = accept_new_tcp_client( listener_fd ); /* this function returns an id not a file descriptor. The fd is saved in client array using the index new_client_id*/

                  /* Do we have a valid client_id */
                  if ( new_client_id >= 0 ){  
                    /* Add this new socket to EPOLL */
                    ev.events = EPOLLIN;            
                    ev.data.ptr = &client[new_client_id];   
                    if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, users[new_client_id].tcp_socket, &ev) < 0) {                 
                        close(client[new_client_id].fd);
                        client[new_client_id].active = 0;
                        client[new_client_id].fd = -1;
                    }    
                  }
            }
            else{
                int current_id, current_fd;
                struct client_data *event_ptr = (struct client_data *)events[i].data.ptr;

                current_id = event_ptr->id;
                current_fd = event_ptr->fd;    

                /* Client uploaded data */  
                if (events[i].events & EPOLLIN ) {   
                    /* pass the fd and id for processing */
                    process_data(current_fd,current_id); 
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what line is throwing the error?  DId you look in the debugger?

Comment: Do you know if `epoll_ctl` fails when adding a new connection?